# Kafka Producer and Consumer Scripts to Run automatically

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka

I have a Django project and I am using pykafka. I have created two files named producer.py and consumer.py inside the project. I have to change directory into the folder where these are present and then separately run python producer.py and consumer.py from the terminal. Everything works great.

I deployed my project online and the web-app is running so I want to run the producer and consumer automatically in the background. How do i do that?

**EDIT 1:** On my production server I did `nohup python name_of_python_script.py &` to execute it in the background. This works for the time being but is it a good solution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically'?

Comment: I meant that it executes automatically on my production server and i do not have do something like python producer.py.

Comment: How about running it as a OS service?

Comment: I just edited the post too. Can you have a look what I did? Does that work?

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a systemd service `MyKafkaConsumer.service` under `/etc/systemd/system` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Kafka Consumer written in Python
After=network.target # include any other pre-requisites 

[Service]
Type=simple
User=your_user
Group=your_user_group
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/consumer
ExecStart=python consumer.py
TimeoutStopSec=180
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In order to start the service (and configure it in order to run on boot) you should run

```
systemctl enable MyKafkaConsumer.service
systemctl start MyKafkaConsumer.service
```

To check its status:

```
systemctl status MyKafkaConsumer
```

And to see the logs:

```
journactl -u MyKafkaConsumer -f
```

(or if you want to see the last 100 lines)

```
journalctl -u MyKafkaConsumer -n 100
```

You'd need to create a similar service for your producer too.

There are a lot of options for systemd services.  You can refer to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) if you need any further clarifications. It shouldn't be hard to find guides and additional material online though.